# Split a numpy array with several sorted sequences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large numpy array (typically a few thousands of numbers) that is consisted of several sorted sequences,
for example:

```
arr = [12, 13, 14, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 9, 10, 11]
```

I would like to split it into subarrays - each one holds another sequence -

```
[12, 13, 14], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [9, 10, 11]
```

What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: the sub array [12, 13, 14, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26] is sorted, why do you split it?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([12, 13, 14, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 9, 10, 11])
splits = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr)!=1)
sub_arrs = np.split(arr, splits+1)
print(sub_arrs)
```

output

```
[array([12, 13, 14]), array([22, 23, 24, 25, 26]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
```

Explanation: I create array with differences between adjacent elements using `numpy.diff` (`np.diff(arr)`) then process it to get array with `True`s where difference is `1` and `False`s in every other case (`np.diff(arr)!=1`) then find indices of `True`s in that array using `np.flatnonzero` (`True` is treated as `1` and `False` is treated as `0` in `python`) finally I use `numpy.split` to get `list` of subarrays made from `arr` at spllited at `splits` offseted by `1` (note that `numpy.diff` returns array which is shorter by 1 than its input).

Side note: I would call this finding sub-arrays with consecutive runs, rather than merely sorted as you might split your `arr` into `[[12, 13, 14, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [9, 10, 11]]` and full-fill requirement that every sub-array is sorted

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the problem could be really complex, but based on your example I assume that the values in subarrays are increasing by 1.

Here is a one liner solution with plain numpy: `np.array_split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 1)[0]+1)`

Explanation: You can calculate the difference between consecutive values with `np.diff`.

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a
array([12, 13, 14, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,  9, 10, 11])
>>> np.diff(a)
array([  1,   1,   8,   1,   1,   1,   1, -17,   1,   1])
```

Then, get the indices of the values that represents the last element of the subarrays, that is the values that do no equal 1.

```
>>> np.where(np.diff(a) != 1)
(array([2, 7]),)
```

Finally, we add 1 to the boundaries to be able to use `np.array_split()` correctly to generate the subarrays.

```
>>> np.where(np.diff(a) != 1)[0]+1
array([3, 8])
>>> np.array_split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 1)[0]+1)
[array([12, 13, 14]), array([22, 23, 24, 25, 26]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
```